# Subversion: How to rerun post-commit scripts for all revisions?

Tags: svn, bug-tracking, post-commit, fogbugz, post-commit-hook

We have installed an integration of our SVN repository with a bug tracker. The bug tracker is called from the post-commit hook to get information about the tickets closed in a commit. Since we have been using the bug tracker for a lot of commits, we would like to rerun (on the server?) the post-commit hook for all commits in our repository. Is there a convenient way?

The bug tracker (FogBugz) does not allow for scanning.

The SVN repository is on a Linux instance with restricted tools (bash, some perl).

Comment: Better on superuser?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way, will cost you one additional repository and some space

- Create full dump of repository (`svnadmin help dump`)
- Create new *empty* repository with needed post-commit hook defined
- load dump from step 1 into repository-skeleton (`svnadmin help load`) with `--use-post-commit-hook` option for applying hook and `--force-uuid` (needed later)
- Delete tree of original repo and copy loaded repository at the location of original (at the same place and with the same UUID *this* repository will be *old* repository for all SVN-clients without switch|relocate)